# Given an integer $n$ and relatively prime positive integer $a$ and $b$, show that exactly one of $n$ and $ab-a-b-n$ is expressible in the form $ax+by$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Given an integer $n$ and relatively prime positive integers $a$ and $b$, show that exactly one of $n$ and $ab-a-b-n$ is expressible in the form $ax+by$ for some non-negative integers $x$ and $y$. Also show that $ab-a-b$ is the largest integer that cannot be expressed in such a form.

I tried this approach for the second problem.

$$ab -a -b = a \cdot (b-1) + b \cdot -1$$

We find that it can be expressed in the form $ax_0 + by_0$ but $y_0$ is negative so this isn't true. Now they can also be expressed in the form

$$ab -a -b = a \cdot (b-1) + b \cdot -1 + ab - ab = a\cdot -1 + b \cdot (-1 + a)$$

So in any case, one of $x_0$ or $y_0$ remains negative and hence it cannot be expressed in such a form.

Now I feel that I can use the proof of the second problem to prove the first problem.

You see, if $n = ax_0 + by_0$ then if $ab - a -b-n$ can be expressed in such a form then $ab-a-b$ can also be. But we have now proved that $ab-a-b$ cannot be expressed thus $ab -a -b-n$ can not be expressed in such a form. This is the proof if $n = ax_0 + by_0$. What if $n \neq ax_0 + by_0$?

How do I proceed with this proof? Is my proof of the second problem correct?

Comment: Hint: prove for any integer there is only one way to express it as $xa+yb$, with $x\in\{0,1,2,3\dots b-1\}$ and $y\in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: At the beginning of your approach, you have found two expressions $ax_0+by_0$ where either $x_0$ or $y_0$ is negative. But these two examples do not show that $x_0$ or $y_0$ *must* be negative. You have not proved the second problem.

Comment: @TheKindCat Why so? For which problem should I do it?

Comment: In this @Théophile? $$ab -a -b = a \cdot (b-1) + b \cdot -1$$ It is clear. You see $y_0 = -1$ is negative.

Comment: @Dhruv for both.

Comment: @Dhruv Yes, clearly $y_0<0$ in that particular expression. That doesn't imply that either $x_0$ or $y_0$ must be negative. Suppose I claim that the number $10$ cannot be expressed as $x_0+y_0$ where $x_0, y_0$ are both non-negative. Proof: consider $10 = -1 + 11$ and $10 = 11 + (-1)$. In the first, $x_0<0$, and in the second, $y_0<0$. Is this a convincing proof?

Comment: @Théophile How do I prove this then? I think that I am subtracting the value of $b$ in $x_0$. Yes, this only holds if $x_0 < b$.

Comment: @TheKindCat Would you be kind enough to explain why for $x \in \{1,2,3,...,b-1\}$, there is only one way to express any integer as $xa + yb$?

Comment: If $m=a x+b y=ax'+ b y'$ with non-negative $x,y,x',y'$ then obviously $y=y'\implies x=x'.$  Suppose $y'>y.$  We have $a(x-x')=b(y'-y) \implies a|b(y'-y)\implies$ $ a|(y'-y)\implies y'=y+z a$  for some  $z>0.$ Hence $m=a x'+b y'=a x'+b(y+ z a)$ $\geq b z a\geq a b.$

Comment: @user254665 So, $m\ge ab$? How is this useful?

Comment: I'm sorry.I'm tired . I was thinking of the fact that for $1\leq m<ab$ there is only one way to write $m=a x +b y.$

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime then $1=ax+by\implies n=a(nx)+b(nx)$. But then both $n$ and $ab-a-b-n$ can be represented in the form $au+bv$. What's exactly the problem asking to prove?

Comment: I believe it is useful after all. Show that for $ a b\leq m \leq 2 a b -1$ there are exactly 2 ways to write m=a x + b y.  We can then use a combinatoric counting argument .I am too tired to give details but I'll check in tomorrow and see whether I should, depending on others' contributions by then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lemma $1$: Given $a$ and $b$ coprime and $n$ any integer there is exactly one way to express $n$ as $ax+by$ with $x\in\{0,1,2\dots b-1\}$ and $y\in\mathbb Z$. We call this representation of $n$ its tight representation.

Proof: By Bezout's theorem there is $s$ and $t$ so that $as+bt=1$. So taking $s'=ns$ and $t'=nt$ we have $as'+bt'=n$. Consider the set $A=\{(x,y) | ax+by=n\}$, we know $(s,t)\in A$. Clearly $(s-b,t+a)$ and $(s+b,t-a)$ are also in $A$. Because of this we can always find a pair $(x,y)\in A$ with $x\in\{0,1,2,\dots,b-1\},y\in\mathbb Z$.

To show uniqueness, suppose $ax+by=n$ and $ax'+by'=n$. Then $a(x-x')+b(y-y')=0$, if $x\neq x'$ then $(x-x')$ is not a multiple of $b$, so $a(x-x')$ is not a multiple of $b$, and $a(x-x')+b(y-y)'$ is not a multiple of $b$, a contradiction, an analogous argument shows $y=y'$.

Lemma $2$: An integer $n$ can be expressed as $sa+tb$ with $s,t$ non negative if and only if the coefficients in its tight representation are non negative.

Proof:  Consider the set $B$ of integer pairs $(s,t)$ so that $s$ is non-negative and $sa+tb=n$. Clearly, the pair $A$ in which $t$ is the largest is also the pair in which $s$ is the smallest, this pair is precisely the tight representation. So if $y$ is negative in the tight representation, then for every pair $(s,t)\in B$ we have $t$ negative.

Problem $1$: Exactly one of $n$ and $ab-a-b-n$ is expressible in the form $ax+by$.

Proof: Let the tight representation of $n$ be $xa+yb$.

Notice $ab-a-b=(b-1)a+(-1)(b)$, so $ab-a-b-n=(b-1-x)a+(-1-y)b$.

So the tight representation of $ab-a-b-n$ is $(b-1-x)a+(-1-y)b$. Clearly exactly one of $y$ and $-1-y$ is non-negative. This finishes the proof.

Problem $2$: The largest integer not expressible in this form is $ab-a-b$. (also known as the chicken McNugget theorem or the frobenius coin problem)

Proof: What can the tight representation of this integer be? Let it be $xa+yb$. Then $x$ is at most $b-1$ and $y$ is at most $-1$ (since it must be negative, so the number is not expressible in this form. We conclude the number is at most $(b-1)a+(-1)b=ab-a-b$.

Comment: Great Proof! Thanks!

Comment: Just another question. What would the tight representation be in case we argue for $ax + by + cz$?

Comment: I mean, how would we choose non-negative $x$,$y$ and $z$?

Comment: I'm not sure, I guess we would have to pick a definition depending on what we want to prove.

Comment: Let $a,b,c$ be pairwise relatively prime positive integers. Show that $2abc − ab − bc − ca$ is the largest integer that cannot be expressed in the form $xbc + yca + zab$, where $x,y,z$ are nonnegative integers. This. Hints?

Comment: Yeah, the "tight" representation is when $x$ is in $\{0,1,2\dots,a-1\}$, $y$ is in $\{0,1,2\dots b-1\}$ and $z$ is in $\mathbb Z$. Notice the number in question is $(a-1)bc+(b-1)ca+(-1)ab$. I hope this helps. The proof is pretty similar, although a bit trickier.

Comment: Why " Chicken McNugget" ?

Comment: IIRC it has something to do with nuggets from Mcdonalds only coming in packages of certain sizes.